# Unable to copy 350 GB data from one bucket to another in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, copy, bucket, google-cloud-data-transfer

I'm trying to move data from one bucket to another bucket within same project on Google Cloud.
It has plain images and documents, like .png, .jpg & .pdf files. I tried several times, but the results remain same.

Below is the command i'm using,
gsutil -m cp -r -n gs://bucket1/folder1/subfolder/* gs://bucket2/folder1/subfolder/ 2>&1 | tee ./result.txt

It runs for few hours, after some time the screen goes to hung state, i'm not seeing any logs running on google console.

My doubt as follows, Is there any setting on GCP that, if the network traffic flows for several hours, it will block the traffic, something like that ?
Is there any size cap in the bucket level ? If yes, How can i check that ?

Do i have to add any additional parameter to the above command ?
Do you have any other suggestions to complete this task ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed "screen" package on the instance and initiated the copy job. Though there was network fluctuations or console getting hung, the job used to run in the backend. Even though its small trick, it was very much helpful to complete the task.
I hope it might help others too. 
Note: I did copy the file & folder not move.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try using [Storage Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/overview/) to complete the task.

> Storage Transfer Service is a product that enables you to:
>
> 1.Move or backup data to a Cloud Storage bucket either from other cloud storage providers or from your on-premises storage.
>
> **> 2.Move data from one Cloud Storage bucket to another, so that it is available to different groups of users or applications**.
>
> 3.Periodically move data as part of a data processing pipeline or analytical workflow.

[Creating and managing data transfers with the Console](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-manage-transfer-console)

## EDIT

You could run the command [perfdiag - Run performance diagnostic](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/perfdiag)

> The perfdiag command runs a suite of diagnostic tests for a given
>   Google Storage bucket.

```
gsutil perfdiag gs://your-bucket
```

If the Availability is not 100% and/or HTTP errors are detected, then there is an indication of a Service/Network Problem

Comment: Yes, I have checked that service too. But it has some limitations.

Comment: The limitations are,
I cannot move/ copy a specific file/ folder from source bucket to specific folder on destination bucket.
Don't have option to select particular file/ folder from source and vice versa.

I'm looking some other options, and wanted think from network traffic control perspective too.

Comment: I got following result:

Total HTTP requests made: 94
HTTP 5xx errors: 0
HTTP connections broken: 0
Availability: 100%

Comment: Could you please try to split the data and then copy from one bucket to other?